# How to disallow to websites install applications without my decision in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Some websites install extensions without my permission. For example when I enter on momondo.com this website installs their extension with name "pkedcjkdefgpdelpbcmbmeomcjbeemfm". How to configure chrome to prevent this behaviour?
[image]

Comment: Websites **cannot** install extensions without your permission. Either you gave them permission, or those are getting "installed" by other software on your machine.

Comment: I know that and I was very surprised about this fact. I made test with another websites but this extension installs just on this website.

Comment: The only way to install extensions by sites was via `chrome.webstore.install` API which this site still uses. The API [was deprecated and disabled](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/inline_faq) in modern Chrome so you either use an old Chrome or there's a bug in Chrome or this site somehow was excluded from the new policy for unclear reason which you can clarify on https://crbug.com.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manage it in your enterprise Google have a [complete guide](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/9296680) for this matter.

you can permanently disable extensions by adding `--disable-extensions` to the end of the target in Chrome shortcut like this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-extensions
```

Alternately you can use windows access control to prevent installation of chrome extensions, just remove write/modify permission from the below path:

```
%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions
```

Right click on Folder - Security - Select User - Remove Write/Modify Permission (you may use Deny but it's not recommended)

Comment: Thank you for useful advice. But not clear how it could happen? I didn't gave permissions to websites and by default chrome shouldn't allow similar behaviour.

Comment: To my knowledge currently there is no extension blocking method on chrome for now, but you may also use some other extensions to manage websites and other extensions or **block website from running scripts in chrome Settings - Advanced - Site Settings**. Regards